# How can I bind scrollwheel to a key in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mouse, autohotkey, scrolling, applescript

I am new to using a Mac, and I have used `AutoHotKey` applications that rebind the mouse scroll wheel (for example, <kbd>E</kbd> = scroll up by 1 mouse wheel "tick" of sorts) to a specific window title, eg. "Game name here" Google chrome)

How could I do that in `AppleScript`? I'm sure it's possible.

I just want to bind the lowercase/capital <kbd>e</kbd> to the mouse wheel scroll up. I have an actual mouse, but for this game, a keybind is more efficient.

How can I do it while having it specific to a certain window title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this AppleScript to scroll up by one line:

```
do shell script "
/usr/bin/python <<'END'
import sys
import time
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import *

def scroll_up():
    event = CGEventCreateScrollWheelEvent(None, kCGScrollEventUnitLine, 1, -1)
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event)

scroll_up()
END"
```

Then you can use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/) to map your keep to that AppleScript. However, this appears to be a *very* slow way of doing things -- not what you'd want for a game. For speed and simplicity, albeit with a cost of $US 5.00, [Keymo](http://manytricks.com/keymo/) can be easily configured to do it.